# RStudio Server together with Microsoft R open: environment variables missing

Tags: r, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04, rstudio, revolution-r

I am running RStudio Server (0.99.879) on Amazon EC2 and have recently updated to Microsoft R Open 3.2.3 (formerly Revolution R). All software runs on Ubuntu 14.04.

Since I wanted to have my Amazon access keys available in all shell sessions for all users, I have put them in `/etc/environment` like `AWS_ACCESS_KEY=123`.

RStudio runs under user `rstudio` which I have checked via executing `system("whoami")` in RStudio. Before switching to Microsoft R Open [MRO], `system("echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY")` (executed from RStudio) gave the correct result `123`. But now it returns an empty string.

However, if I switch to user `rstudio` in the console via `su - rstudio` and start MRO from the *shell*, `system("echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY")` gives the correct result, which really puzzles me.

It seems as if only RStudio *together* with MRO makes R forget the environment variables defined in `etc/environment`.

**Do you guys know what could be the reason for this strange behavior? Any pointers to possible fixes?**

I would really like to keep the keys in just one place (which is `/etc/environment`) and definitely not hard coded in my R code. One fix that I could think of is to read `/etc/environment` from R, extract the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and set it via `Sys.setenv()`. But this is mostly just a hack and I would like to understand what the real problem is...

BTW: Maybe I should mention that I had to change the `R_HOME_DIR` variable in the R start script `/usr/bin/R` to `R_HOME_DIR=/usr/lib64/MRO-3.2.3/R-3.2.3/lib/R` because the code that was determining the home directory before did not work with MRO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to keep in mind that RStudio Server (the open source edition) does not run user sessions under a login shell. So when you `su - rstudio`, you're getting the shell variables that are initialized when bash starts.

Thankfully there's a pretty easy way around this: symlink  `R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site` (see [R initialization](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html)) to `/etc/environment`. R's environment files have the same format as Linux's (i.e. KEY=VALUE), so you can supply the same list of environment initializers to both R and bash.

Comment: Great! Actually, I have thought that this problem is so specific that it's very unlikely to get an answer. But today was my lucky day as it seems. :) Since everything works fine with the regular R version, I guess that Revolution (or Microsoft) has changed something in the start-up procedures. Anyhow, just in case someone is interested, here the command that creates the link `sudo ln -s /etc/environment /usr/lib64/MRO-3.2.3/R-3.2.3/lib/R/etc/Renviron.site`. One might have to change the last path to one's specific MRO installation path, though.

Comment: OMG, completely forgot that I had already code that reads and processes `/etc/environment` in `R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site` for regular R. So, riddle solved: MRO has another `Rprofile.site` file where I did not set these variables. But I will keep @Jonathan's solution as it is much cleaner and easier.